# Showing that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n = \int_0^1\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

How to solve the following task:

> Show that if $f_n$ is a sequence of uniformly converging mappings $f_n \in C[0,1]$, where $C[0,1]=\{f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R} \;\mid\; f\;
>  \text{continuous}\}$ then $$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\int_0^1 f_n =
>  \int_0^1\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim} f_n$$

How to tackle this problem? Should I consider using some metric function here or?

Comment: Hi @ClementC. you're right. Let me double check my problem statement.

Comment: I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
\left\lvert \int_0^1 f_n - \int_0^1 f\right\rvert \leq 
 \int_0^1 \left\lvert f_n - f\right\rvert \leq 
 \int_0^1 \lVert f_n - f\rVert_\infty = \lVert f_n - f\rVert_\infty.
$$
What does uniform convergence give you then?

Comment: Hi @ClementC I think you got it right. I had a confusion with the notation in my problem statement I think. Thank you! =)

Comment: You're welcome.